# show/hide button

Tags: javascript, animation, button

I inserted a few show/hide button on my application. 
My problem is: when I click on any button always is opened first. 
That's the function:

```
function showHide(shID) {
  if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
    if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
      document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
      document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
    }
  } 
}
```

And this is my insert function:

```
function insert($string)
{
    $result = '<div id="wrap">

            <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide(\'example\');return false;">Vizualizare</a></p>
        <div id="example" class="more">
            <p> '. $string .'</p>
            <p><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide(\'example\');return false;">Ascunde</a></p>
        </div>
                </div>';
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to show the div 'example' when clicking on the link 'example-show' ?

Comment: Is that PHP on the bottom?  Should probably add a PHP tag if it is...

Comment: You should use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)!

Comment: @Steve: Why? The actual question is about JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You always provide the same argument to showHide(), so the  ID of the element will always be the same. But IDs have to be unique.

Instead of using IDs traverse the document starting from the clicked button.

Example:

```
function showHide(btn)
{
  var target;
  if(btn.parentNode.parentNode.className=='more')
  {
    target=btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  }
  else
  {
    target=btn.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
  }

  target.style.display=(target.style.display == 'block')?'none':'block';  
  target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.display
    =(target.style.display != 'none')?'none':'block';
}
```

Provide here only `this` (without quotes) as argument to `showHide()`

Watch the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/kZDvh/

Comment: And in this case use jQuery so your code doesn't become insane ;)

Comment: how do i use jquery here?
please give me an example
I'm new to jquery
And i got a project and i must finish it tommorow. Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to use jQuery here. If you don't use it yet you shouldn't load it only for this one functionality . The code above works without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

as there is no display:none for either btn-show or div-example, so initially they will be both visible. then base on the sequence of if-then in your function, whether you click which button first, browser will always hide the show-button and make div-example display:block. so maybe you need to hide one of them initially by some css or js set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span><div>
<input type="button" value="Show" onclick="if (this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display != '') { this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = ''; this.value = 'Hide'; } else { this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'none'; this.value = 'Show'; }" style="font-size: 11px; cursor: pointer;">
</div>
<div class="alt2" style="border: 0px inset; margin: 0px; padding: 6px;">
<div style="display: none;"> <!-- Is content default show: remove none -->

    <!-- Content Show/Hide Here -->

</div>
</div></span>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I believe this answer could be even better with a little bit of explanation alongside your code. Particularly in your `onclick` section, because inline JavaScript like that can be hard to read.

Comment: @BrianJ I'm sory,  not understand your question, my English is very bad.
I if understand: no difficulty in reading because the command comes before the target. and I put the <span> if  want to repeat the button.